# ceiling time_point to runtime defined duration

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, ceil

I'm ceiling time_point to next full five minutes, which is quite easy:

```
template <int N>
    using minutes = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<N>, std::chrono::minutes::period>>;

const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
const auto begin = ceil<minutes<5>>(now);
```

I don't know how to set the count of minutes at runtime.

Comment: `std::chrono::minutes(X)`?

Comment: You'll have to do the arithmetic yourself.  There is no chrono-supplied API to do this.

Comment: What precision would you like to have the resultant `time_point` to have?  I can see three reasonable answers:  1) The precision of the input `time_point` (`system_clock::duration` in this example).  2)  The precision of the input `duration` (`minutes` in this example).  3)  The `common_type` of 1) and 2) (`system_clock::duration` in this example).

Comment: I just need to ceil to next round 5 minutes, without seconds, milliseconds...
I need time_points in hour x -> x:00, x:05, x:10, ..., x:55
My example do what I want, but it's compile time solution, for e.g. ceiling to 10 or 1 I need to recompile it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `ceil` function that will take any `time_point` and round it up to the next `Duration m`, while giving the result a precision of `Duration{1}`:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration1, class Duration2>
constexpr
auto
ceil(std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration1> t, Duration2 m) noexcept
{
    using R = std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration2>;
    auto r = std::chrono::time_point_cast<Duration2>(R{} + (t - R{})/m*m);
    if (r < t)
        r += m;
    return r;
}
```

It can be used like:

```
const auto begin = ceil(system_clock::now(), 5min);
const auto begin = ceil(system_clock::now(), 10min);
const auto begin = ceil(system_clock::now(), 10ms);
```

1. First the return type is computed and given the alias `R`.
2. Then the `time_point` `t` is truncated to the `duration` `m` (towards zero).
3. If the truncated result is less than the input, the result is rounded up to the next `m`.

If 24 hours is not evenly divisible by `m`, the result may be counterintuitive.